# Strange casting behavior in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, casting, implicit-conversion

Here is the code

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE id = '1h';
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set
```

There is indeed a field with id 1 (but not '1h').
Here is an extraction from MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html

```
mysql> SELECT 1 > '6x';
    -> 0
mysql> SELECT 7 > '6x';
    -> 1
```

So this bug is documented, so to say. The question is what's the reason for such behavior and how to correct it to make this not cast strings with char symbols? I can cast all field values like

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE cast(`id`, BINARY) = '1h';
```

but i don't like this variant too much

Comment: What is the type of your `id` column? I'm guessing it's numeric? I really don't see a bug here. If you force MySQL to convert between types, you need to understand *how* it does type conversion.

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, it's int. And i dln't convert it explicitly

Comment: Is there no solution yet to prevent this on the MYSQL end? I noticed this problem especially when a page generates a query for a numeric column using input supplied by the user. Obviously, a user can suppy "1h" and mysql will still read "1" and return a result. If there is no MYSQL setting OR collation type to override the casting, then are we left with checking the datatype for every user-supplied input for numeric parameters? That would be a lot of code review and refactoring!

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug.

The solution is **not** to query on numeric columns using a string value for your condition.

**Never** rely on implicit type casting.

Comment: Actually the solution is to ***never*** rely on implicit type casting.

Comment: It doesn't help. I mean is there a way to turn this kind of conversion off? To convert just strings without chars in them?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you don't mind, added this to my answer.

Comment: @kos How do you build this query?

Comment: @kos: what language are you using to generate the queries? Most decent libraries should handle this thing for you.

Comment: @Dancrumb (and others) I don't rely on it. It's CodeIgneter's ActiveRecord behavior

Comment: @kos So you use PHP. I guess this string comes from user input. Always validate and filter every input that comes from outside. If you expect a number, only accept a number, don't run the query otherwise. I'm not familiar with CI though, someone might have a specific solution for that.

Comment: @bažmegakapa: I know and that's not the case. I got this casting problem can't be solved, but still remains the question what's the reason of such implicit conversion, when a string in where clause is obviously not supposed to be a number

Comment: @kos If the reason "MySQL works like this" is not enough, then I can't really help (maybe the creators could). The only solution I can offer is that you should not run the query if the parameter does not satisfy your validation rules.

Comment: @kos: PostgreSQL would simply throw an exception. MySQL thinks it's clever and tries to return something - even if it's the wrong thing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanx. You've added one more reason to switch to PostgreSQL. Answers like "it's there because it's there" don't clarify how this feature (feature??) is supposed to be used and what's it added for. For me it's still a bug, documented though

Comment: @kos Just found this: [MySQL: Server SQL Modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html). Might be relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of your observations are bugs. They are the result of relying in implicit type casting.

In all of your examples, you're requiring MySQL to convert a string to an int. If you read the very page that you linked to, you will see that MySQL follows some rules in achieving this. As a result

```
'1h' -> 1
'6x' -> 6
'x6' -> 0
```

So, if you follow these rules, you'll be OK.

Better still, just don't put MySQL in a position where it needs to be doing these conversion. Such situations usually point to some kind of logic bug elsewhere in the system.