# Simple select issue with -(dash) in where clause

Tags: mysql

I need to search for a value like `1234-abc`. The database doesn't have this particular value, but has another value `1234`. Now the problem is when I write my query like

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE tval='1234-abc'
```

instead of fetching an empty recordset, it fetches the `1234` value, it seems to ignore anything after the `-`, any idea what's going on?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de62/3

Comment: That should work - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34b05/1. `Record Count: 0`. Do you have anything special in your schema? Any triggers, any unusual setup?

Comment: Nope...except it being both a primary key and part of another grouped index, there isn't anything weird

Comment: post your create table query

Comment: OOPS, sorry guys, I made a mistake while posting the sample case...the thing is, the column is of type INT(11), that's why I think it is trying to convert the value to int before checking.  But this still poses a problem...since I need it to return blank, not the integer value.

I updated my question above. I am really sorry for the wrong data earlier, here is the fiddle too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de62/3

Comment: @aoi So, thats why you have to check your create script or post create script and query when you have to ask questions... :)

Comment: I know, but it is part of a large table, that's why I just typed it out, which I admit, was my mistake.Anyway, how do I get mysql to be not so smart, and not convert it to int?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange casting behavior in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365824/strange-casting-behavior-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `BINARY` keyword for the exact match

```
 SELECT tval FROM words WHERE BINARY  tval='1223-abc';
```

[**Binary**](http://gilfster.blogspot.com/2005/08/case-sensitivity-in-mysql.html) is a built-in keyword that after your `WHERE` clause that forces a comparison for an *exact* case-sensitive match

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de62/16)

Comment: It's help me also.

Answer (score 1):

The existing expression is implicitly converting the string expression to a number - you need to explicitly convert the number to a character strng, like so:

```
SELECT tval FROM words WHERE convert(tval,char(20))='1223-1ABCDE';
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9de62/12).